# Is there any tool to anlyze audio specturm of a song and give the average visually ?

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have a lot of songs I made over the 20 years and was thinking it would be interesting to see how the overall EQ changed on the various songs I made.

Any tool out there to help me with something like this ?

Comment: By EQ, do you mean the energy at different frequencies? It sounds to me like the [spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) could be useful to you.

Comment: Yes.. I know about real time analyzers but I am looking for something that can take the complete average of a song.. Not just the values in one particular spot

Comment: That would simply be the Fourier transform, which you would show you the relative energy over the the frequency spectrum, but I'm not sure that's really what you're asking for.

Comment: I do have PreSonus studio one and Ozone.. Ill have to see if there is a feature to average out the whole song.. Or atleast a few seconds ?

Answer (score -1):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/?lang=zh-EN) will let you look at a song's spectrum/spectrogram, and it works with most audio formats.

It's also free!

Comment: Audacity is limited to relatively small windows - so it will not allow the visualization of the spectrum of the entire song.

Comment: I just tested Audacity on a wav file (2 channels, 16 bits/sample 44.1k samples/second). Maximum window size for spectrum analysis is 237.8 seconds (about 4 minutes).